# Bezier Cubic Curves for six points

Tags: real-analysis, bezier-curve

Given six points in $\Bbb R^2$: $(-1,0),(-1,1),(-1,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2)$.

> How to prove that there is not Cubic Bezier curve that cross all these points?

[The picture of the points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgtPZ.png)

Comment: That $x(t)=-1$ three times is doable. That $x(t)=+1$ three times as well. But the order in which the points are passed must be $x=-1,+1,+1,-1-1,+1$ in that order (or backwards). I guess that for all possible orders, $y(t)$ must have two many local extrema to be cubic?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thank you for answer. But I can not understand, why the order must be for x -1,1,1,-1,-1,1

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Sorry but I think that I don't understand full your solution

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen The order of X(t) I understand.

Comment: Does the curve have to pass through the six points in the order given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it *is* possible, if we're allowed to interpolate the six points in any order we choose:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for a cubic polynomial to take the values $-1$ and $1$ three times, when it has two extrema. But only the sequence $-1,1,1,-1,-1,1$ (increasing, decreasing, increasing) or its opposite are possible.

[image]

Note that on $y$, the sequence $0,1,2,0,1,2$ is possible.